# Shown on timeline not default selection

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, posting

I am following the instructions posted on here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#define

It adds the item to my timeline, but I can only view it by going to Activity Log, once I hover over the button on the far right, its default selection is Allowed on Timeline, once I click Shown on Timeline, it appears.

Is there any way to default an application posting on someone's timeline to appear(shown on timeline) by default?

Comment: I am interested in this question to, did you find any answer?

Comment: I'm also fumbling - did you find an answer?

Comment: I think Pinterest does this.  I do not use Pinterest so I have not confirmed, but I read an article saying they have the option on their end (not Facebook's end) to "Show on Timeline" by default when new content is added to the Pinterest account.

Answer (score 0):

I fumbled over the permissions page. There is no permission we can ask user to do this automatically.